# Issue with run python code by terminal linux: module keras.backend has no attribute get_session

Tags: python-3.x, linux, keras

i try to run python code and i get the error:

```
attributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_session'
```

i tried to search here and on network, i did not find anything.

- tensorflow 2.2.0
- keras 2.4.3
- python 3.6.9

TNX

Comment: Which Keras version? Which tensorflow version?

Comment: tensorflow 2.2.0  .....   keras 2.4.3